# getaddrinfo: No such host is known

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, xml-rpc

I am trying to setup a wordpress `xml-rpc` with rails:

```
blog = XMLRPC::Client.new("localhost/blog", "/xmlrpc.php", 80)
```

However, when I try to call something like

```
connection.call(
          'wp.getCommentCount',
          1,
          'username',
          'password',
          1
```

I get the following error:

```
getaddrinfo: No such host is known.
```

This only happens in my `localhost` (I'm using `xampp`), on the live website it works fine. What can this be?

If I go directly to `localhost/blog/xmlrpc.php` I get **XML-RPC server accepts POST requests only.** which means it's working fine. I don't understand what can be messing this up... thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead, try

```
blog = XMLRPC::Client.new("localhost", "/blog/xmlrpc.php", 80)
```

I have this tested on my WordPress site and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `"http://localhost/blog"` and not `"localhost/blog"`.

Comment: Thanks Gerry, but the problem is not in the url. I'm not sure what it is but I can't seem to fix it. I've been testing it against the server rather than working on my local machine.

Comment: Yes, definitely not the address. Thanks again.